# Allow http requests once a user ssh'es in

Tags: ssh, apache-2.2, authentication

I got a secure web server (apache) that denies users if they don't come from a certain IP.

Sometimes my ip changes, and I want it to allow me.

One way I was thinking was automatically add the ip once I ssh in.  Since ssh'ing is done via passphrase auth, it's pretty secure.

Does anyone have any ideas of implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you register a host name at one of the several dynamic dns providers and add this host name to your apache "allow from" configuration?

You can register and get a fixed host name at http://www.dyndns.com/ (there are many others) and follow the instructions there on how to update your dynamic IP when changed. There are several way to do this, some routers have this already implemented, if not you would need to install a dyndns update client.